# How to concatenate strings and integer in a variable

Tags: python

I have a variable of `int` type.
I am running for loop on it and making a variable with adding some string info.

```
a = 5 // variable with integer value
list = '' // empty variable
for x in range(a):
  list.append('MA[' + x + '] |')
```

Expected output:

```
MA[5] | MA[4] | MA[3] | MA[2] | MA[1] | MA[0]
```

Comment: Note that you'll get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`. And apart from that, `str.join` - what you want can be written as `' | '.join('MA[%d]' % i for i in ...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Frank points out, `list` is a string which has no `.append()` method. You *seriously* should rename it to something more meaningful, but at the very least don't confuse the reader of your code (yourself included!) by naming  a string `list`. Renaming it to `string` and using `str()` to cast `x` to a string:

```
string += 'MA[' + str(x) + '] |'
```

Or better, learn [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). In this case it would be:

```
string += 'MA[%d] | % x
```

You'll also need to change 5 t 6 if you want to iterate over the range 0-5 inclusive. And if you want to iterate in reverse, use `range(a, -1, -1)`.

Here's a generator combined with `join()`:

```
>>> ' | '.join('MA[%d]' % x for x in xrange(5, -1, -1))
'MA[5] | MA[4] | MA[3] | MA[2] | MA[1] | MA[0]'
```

Comment: +1 for finding the most errors and showing a textbook solution.

Comment: @delnan With the help of others here!

Answer (score 1):

Use string formatting. In Python 2.x:

```
list += ('MA[%s] |' % x)
```

The whole thing can more easily be written with a list comprehension and `join`:

```
my_list = ' | '.join('MA[%s]' % x for x in reversed(xrange(a)))
```

Also, don't call your variables `list`, that shadows the built-in function.

Comment: `%d` (is this the weFail question? :P)

Comment: +1 for margcog's comment, although strictly speaking `%s` works as well (it's just not the best choice semantically, behaves different for e.g. `%02(d|s)` and unlike `%d` it won't catch non-integers).

Comment: what's the big difference between `%d` and `%s`? Both give the same result here. Is `%d` faster?

Comment: @Frank `%d` formats an integer, `%s` a string. Since `x` is an integer, best use `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version with a generator expression:

```
>>> ' | '.join('MA[%s]' % x for x in range(5))
'MA[0] | MA[1] | MA[2] | MA[3] | MA[4]'
```

I also don't know why the other answers use `.append`. Strings don't have that method. Just because a variable is called `list` doesn't mean it is one.

Also note that your desired output is reversed. `range(5)` gives you `[0,1,2,3,4]` to iterate through. So your elements are created in the other order (from 0 up to 4) and do not include a 5..

Comment: Gar, caught out by the `list` name.

Comment: Drop the pointless list comprehension. Generator expressions are your friend.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer delnan. Still use the list comprehensions too often out of habit.

Comment: thanks frank for the promt ans. can you point me to some advance doc for python

Comment: Please use `'MA[{0}]'.format( x ) for x in range(5)` instead of the `%` operator.  `%` will go away in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want you need also to revert the list on which you iterate:
very simple example:

```
a = 5
lst = ''
it_list = range(a+1)
it_list.reverse()
for x in it_list:
    lst += 'MA[' + str(x) + '] |'

print lst[:-3]
```

Output:

```
MA[5] | MA[4] | MA[3] | MA[2] | MA[1] | MA[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

1. You are using a bad comment-string format - Python uses the pound char (#)
2. calling a variable 'list' is bad because it 'writes over' the list() constructor
3. worse, you are making "list" a string!
4. You are trying to use the list append() method - but because you have defined "list" as a string, and there is no string append() method, it fails
5. You are iterating backwards from the desired output (you are going '0 up to 4', not '5 down to 0')
6. You have an off-by-one error - Python does not include the last value in a range, so range(5) returns 0,1,2,3,4

Try:

```
def makeCallString(n, fmt="MA[{0}]", jn=" | "):
    "Return string consisting of fmt[n] + jn + fmt[n-1] + jn + ... + fmt[0]"
    return jn.join(fmt.format(a) for a in range(n, -1, -1))
```

Then

```
makeCallString(5)
```

returns

```
MA[5] | MA[4] | MA[3] | MA[2] | MA[1] | MA[0]
```

as a string.